# How to check where currently used controller inherits from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 application I've got two controllers:

```
class Context::FrontendController < ApplicationController
end
```

---

```
class Context::BackendController < ApplicationController
end
```

All my other controllers (and there are a lot of them) inherit from either the first one **or** the second one (but never both).

---

In my views I sometimes need to show or hide certain elements depending on if the current controller inherits from the `FrontendController` **OR** the `BackendController`.

How can this check be done?

Comment: "but never both" - because this is impossible in ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my views I sometimes need to show or hide certain elements depending on if the current controller inherits from the FrontendController OR the BackendController.
>
> How can this check be done?

You can do this check (as shown by @mechnicov), but you shouldn't. Instead, use OOP.

```rb
class ApplicationController
  def current_area
    # raise NotImplementedError
    :none
  end
  helper_method :current_area
end

class FrontendController < ApplicationController
  def current_area
    :frontend
  end
end

class BackendController < ApplicationController
  def current_area
    :backend
  end
end
```

Then

```
<% if current_area == :frontend %>
```

You can prettify this as you wish (make methods `frontend?` / `backend?`, etc.)

Comment: One cool trick is to return always return an [ActiveSupport::StringInquirer](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/StringInquirer.html) instance from the method which will let you do `if current_area.frontend?` and `if current_area.backend?`.

Answer (score 2):

In your view you can use something like

```
<% if controller.class.ancestors.include?(Context::BackendController) %>
  <%= show.some.content %>
<% end %>
```

May be create some helper

```
def inherited_from?(controller_class)
  controller.class.ancestors.include?(controller_class)
end
```

And then

```
<% if inherited_from?(Context::BackendController) %>
  <%= show.some.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting `uninitialized constant ActionView::Context::BackendController` when I use this in my views.

Comment: @Tintin81 you can change it to `::Context::BackendController`

Comment: `obj.class.ancestors.include?(...)` should be equivalent to `obj.is_a?(...)`

Comment: @Stefan or with alias `kind_of?`